# Null Pointer ExceptionSpring boot jpa

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa

I have the next piece of code:

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
  @EnableScheduling
  public class GeolocalizacionApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(GeolocalizacionApplication.class, args);
    }

  }
```

Dao

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UsigRequestPersistanceDaoImpl implements UsigRequestPersistanceDao {

 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;

 public List<UsigRequestPersistance> getRequest() {

 Query query =  em.createQuery("select v.requestId from UsigRequestSeq v").getFirstResult();


 }
```

}

Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "seq_usig_request", schema = "xxxx")
public class UsigRequestSeq {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "request_id", nullable = false)
  private Integer requestId;

   public Integer getRequestId() {
      return requestId;
   }

   public void setRequestId(Integer requestId) {
      this.requestId = requestId;
   }

}
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("xxxx");
            sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return sessionFactoryBean;
        }


        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource(){
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");

            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:teradata://teradata.xxxx/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8");


            dataSource.setUsername("xxxx");
            dataSource.setPassword("xxxx");

            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean(name = "properties")
        public Properties hibernateProperties(){
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect");
            //properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            return properties;
        }
        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(){
                HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
                hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());    
            return hibernateTransactionManager;
        }



}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Then I do have a controller, but I think it's not necessary to put it here. In my controller y havec a method which calls getRequest() method.

Here I have some of the stack

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.xxxx.Geolocalizacion.dao.UsigRequestPersistanceDaoImpl.getRequest(UsigRequestPersistanceDaoImpl.java:82) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.xxxx.Geolocalizacion.controller.GeoController.ejecutar(GeoController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

I believe that I have problems with the createQuery native method, I debug the program and there's where it breaks, but I can´t finds why. Am I missing something?

Comment: Remove the call getFirstResult() method, looks as possible null pointer and let me know what happens

Comment: maybe your `em` or `em.createQuery` is null , try to debug to see whitch one is null , but can you tell why you did not use `jpaRepository` to facilitate the job rather than using native query and all these configurations ?

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to use jpaRepository to avoid problems.